# How is Facebook able to autoplay videos on mobile browsers

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile, html5-video, facebook-javascript-sdk

I realize that many questions have been asked about autoplay videos on mobile devices but before my question is marked as a duplicate, I must say that I looked through a lot of those questions and answers and I have not found a satisfactory answer.

Mostly, all of the answers say that it's not possible to autoplay videos on mobile browsers.

My question: **How can Facebook autoplay videos on mobile browsers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos can only be started by user interaction. This is usually clicking a button but you can also use any of the touch events (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

To replicate the functionality, you can use `touchmove` to detect the user scrolling through the page and use it to trigger a play when the video is visible.

Comment: thanks for that, but I would like to find out how to autoplay videos on mobile, like Facebook.

Comment: @joeR That is how you would autoplay a video on mobile. Facebook videos only autoplay when you are scrolling.

Comment: Looks like you're right, it's not autoplay on page load. Thanks.